# Connect to oracle 11 on a corporate network via oracle developer 17

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sql-developer, plsql-developer

Sorry for this absolute oracle noob question:

I am in an environment that uses integrated / active directory authentication, for developer to access the oracle databases via an old version 9 PL/SQL Developer:

[image]

Clicking OK gets me into the dababase

I am trying to connect to the same database via Oracle SQL Developer 17 and the login screen is more complicated:
[image]

What do I enter here? I've searched far and wide but there are few resources for an oracle noob like me.

Comment: SID should be EDBDEV, Connection Name = "Anything you want...", Username/Password as for previous connection. Hostname - whatever that is (or IP). Ask the sysadmin if it's running on 1521.

Comment: @Vérace so I have all the info (hostname and port) and I enter the database name for SID, but I get this : "Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
 "

Comment: Is there nobody you can ask about this? I mean, surely your colleagues must access this database also? It's a dev machine I take it? What do the other devs do? Can you access the host machine with sqlplus? What about a shell account? What happens when you run `lnsrctl` (or similar - can't remember exact name - been a while since I've been on Oracle!)

Comment: @Vérace no, no one is interested in using sql developer, they are happy with pl/sql developer they have. So no, i am on my own :)

Comment: How does the EDBEV option appear on the dropdown in your PL/SQL Developer? It must be obtaining that list from somewhere? You find out where developers add new machines/servers/SIDs to that list and then you look at the config for those - there has to be something for EDBEV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PL/SQL Developer can only connect to an Oracle database using what's known as a TNS Alias.

This is defined a file called "tnsnames.ora" that contains some text something a bit like this (shamelessly stolen from @Balazs's answer):

```
EDBDEV =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = edbdev.mycompany.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = EDBDEV)
    )
  )
```

This allows administrators to define database names and "hide" the IP address/service name details from end users.  They say "connect to EDBDEV" and that's all you need to know.

The location of this file is defined by the variable "TNS_ADMIN".  On a Linux system you'd find this by typing:

```
echo $TNS_ADMIN
```

On a Windows box you can find it by opening the command prompt and typing:

```
echo %TNS_ADMIN%
```

In SQL Developer, you can change the "Connection type" box to "TNS", and it will present you with a list of the TNS Aliases that it knows about - e.g. those that it found in the file:

```
%TNS_ADMIN%\tnsnames.ora
```

If for some reason you need to override this location, you can set the location of the TNSNames.ora file manually in the preferences:

```
Tools / Preferences / Database / Advanced
```

Comment: your explanation assumes the use of TNS_ADMIN, which is not required and really not used all that often.  Without it, tns will look first in the current directory, then in $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin.  And with SQL Dev having its own jdbc thin client, it's quite possible to not have the oracle client (and thus, no $ORACLE_HOME) at all.

Answer (score 1):

`EDBDEV` is a TNS alias.

If you search for a file called `tnsnames.ora`, that should contain an entry similar to below:

```
EDBDEV =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = edbdev.mycompany.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = EDBDEV)
    )
  )
```

Based on that, you can fill in the required connection details.

Comment: I've tried looking for this file but no cigar - no such file exists. Any other place this code be defined?

Comment: Maybe on someone else's machine?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but need to note a few items:
First, since you are defining your "connection type" as "basic", SQL Dev will be using it's built-in jdbc thin client, and so will NOT be using tnsnames.ora.  If you changed your connection type to "tns", you would get a different set of fields, including a drop-list that is populated by the entries in tnsnames.  But stick to 'basic' connection and you don't have to worry about that.

Second, instead of setting SID=edbdev, use service name=edbdev.

Not part of the answer, but I find it astounding and shameful (on their part) that your colleagues have no interest in helping you at all.  Especially for something like this. The gui interface make look a little different, but the fundamentals of connecting a client to the database are the same regardless of the client product. And so the information needed by the client is the same.